# Foreach with multiple await function execute twice the length of indexes of an array

Tags: c#, foreach, async-await

### I have been struggle to find the solution for this.

I have a foreach loop

```
int[] guardianContacts = {1,2,3};
foreach (var s in guardianContacts)
{
    string response = await _messageRepo.SendMessage(s.ContactNumber, model.TextMessage);
    SmsDetails modelDetails = new SmsDetails
    {
        SmsType = "manual",
        StudentGuardianId = s.StudentGuardianId,
        AspNetUserId = member.Id,
        DateSent = DateTime.Now,
        Status = response,
        Message = model.TextMessage
    };
 await _messageRepo.InsertSmsDetails(modelDetails);
```

}

It is clear that the variable `guardianContacts` has only 3 indexes.

But when it execute. it loops twice the number of indexes length, In this example i have 3 when i run it, it loops 6 times. May i ask why is this happening? and by the way i'am using `async and await`.

**UPDATE:**

`var guardianContacts = {1,2,3};` to `int[] guardianContacts = {1,2,3};`

note: This line of code `string response = await _messageRepo.SendMessage(s.ContactNumber, model.TextMessage);` calls an api request.

i did something like this to check how many times it loops without the awaitable calls, the output as expected is `3`

```
int[] guardianContacts = {1,2,3};
int ctr = 0
foreach (var s in guardianContacts)
{
    ctr++;
}
```

Comment: `var guardianContacts = {1,2,3};` does not compile

Comment: thanks @Jonesopolis, please see the updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that, i have multiple reference of `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` that is why it invoke twice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace

```
 var guardianContacts = {1,2,3};
```

with

```
int[] guardianContacts = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

The following code:

```
        int[] guardianContacts = { 1, 2, 3 };
        foreach (var s in guardianContacts)
        {
            Response.Write(s + "<br />");
            Response.Flush();
        }
```

Output

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: This should be comment as OP clearly able to run some code... Just different from what provided in the post...